# App Delegate not being called on Spotify callback

Tags: ios, swift, spotify

My problem is a lot like [this issue](https://github.com/spotify/ios-sdk/issues/772). When running [Spotify in Swift](https://github.com/Sethmr/SpotifyInSwift/), I was able to goto the player yesterday. Today when I built my app, it would call

```
UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:],
                                      completionHandler: {
                                        (success) in
                                        print("Open success \(success)")
```

and then print out the URL on callback from this in the App Delegate:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: Any) -> Bool {
        // Ask SPTAuth if the URL given is a Spotify authentication callback
        print("The URL: \(url)")
        if SPTAuth.defaultInstance().canHandle(url) {
            SPTAuth.defaultInstance().handleAuthCallback(withTriggeredAuthURL: url) { error, session in
                // This is the callback that'll be triggered when auth is completed (or fails).
                if error != nil {
                    print("*** Auth error: \(error)")
                    return
                }
                else {
                    SPTAuth.defaultInstance().session = session
                }
                NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name.init(rawValue: "sessionUpdated"), object: self)
            }
        }
        return false
    }
```

There hasn't been any changes in my code to do with the Spotify log in flow.
I also got this error once:

```
-canOpenURL: failed for URL: "spotify-action://" - error: "The operation couldn’t be completed.
```